# Tried to make sort ordering db using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I Tried of making sort of names using Codeigniter but I found a problem, Please help me

Here is my data

1. Doe Blablabla
2. blablalba doe blablabla
3. blablabla doe
4. doe

I wanna sort it becomes like below but with some limit

1. doe
2. doe blablabla
3. blablabla doe blablala
4. blablabla doe

**And here's my code, but the sort won't work yet**

```
public function getFilter($name)
  {
$this->db->select("*, (CASE people
    WHEN people = '$name' THEN 1
    WHEN people LIKE '$name%' THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END) as people_name");
    $this->db->from('citizen');
    $this->db->like('people', $id);
    $this->db->order_by("people_name asc");
    $this->db->limit(2);  
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }
```